# How do I conver to binary if I have fewer bits?

Tags: binary

I'm given a 6 bit exponent range and a 4 bit mantissa range (MMMM|EEEEEE). I want to convert the number 171.125 to this form.

Converting both parts to binary I get 10101011.11111101 and normalising I have

1.0101011 11111101 x 2^7.

I found that the bias in this case is not 127 but it's given by a formula which gives the bias as 31.  So for the 6-bit exponential part : exp-31=7=>exp=38=100110

However, my mantissa range is too small. What do I do with the fractional part?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point (im)precision. You can only store 4 bits (implicitly 5) and the rest is lost.

Comment: So I just store the 4 first digits ? Or do I round something ? What do I do in this example ?

Comment: You store the first four bits `0101 | 100110` which ends up truncating the binary value.